# Change color shape with a macro

Tags: vba, excel

I want change the color of a shape with a macro.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 20")).Select
If Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse Then
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Solid
Else: Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
End If

If Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue Then
Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
Else: Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Solid
End If
```

Now I want when there is no filling that it gets red and when the filling is red it get no filling.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub ToggleMe2Colors()
    Dim sShape As Shape
    Set sShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)

    With sShape.Fill
        If .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) = True Then
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        Else
            .Visible = True
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim wsh As Worksheet: Set wsh = ActiveSheet
Dim shp As Shape: Set shp = wsh.Shapes("Rectangle 20")

With shp.Fill
    .Visible = Not .Visible ' Toggle fill on/off
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Set the color
End With
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I'am looking for.

Comment: Is it also possible to make a macro for switching the color of a shape between RGB(255, 0, 0) and RGB(0, 176, 80)?